# Send packets through internet using Pcapdotnet

Tags: c#, .net, pcap.net

I want to use pcapdotnet to send packet to my free web site, but there are no packets received, can any one tell me where is my fault,

my web site address: www.infinitypower.somee.com
I use ping to get the ip address: 204.27.56.226
the code:

```
using System;

namespace ClientApplication
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            fillDevice();
        }

        private void btnInvoke_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Take the selected adapter
            if (lsDevice.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                PcapDotNet.Core.PacketDevice selectedDevice = (PcapDotNet.Core.PacketDevice)lsDevice.SelectedItem;

                // Open the output device
                using (PcapDotNet.Core.PacketCommunicator communicator = selectedDevice.Open(100, PcapDotNet.Core.PacketDeviceOpenAttributes.Promiscuous, 1000))
                {   
                    communicator.SendPacket(BuildEthernetPacket());
                }
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Select device from the list");

        }

        private void fillDevice()
        {
            lsDevice.Items.Clear();

            IList allDevices = PcapDotNet.Core.LivePacketDevice.AllLocalMachine;

            if (allDevices.Count == 0)
            {
                lsDevice.Items.Add("No interfaces found! Make sure WinPcap is installed.");
                return;
            }

            // Print the list
            for (int i = 0; i != allDevices.Count; ++i)
            {
                PcapDotNet.Core.LivePacketDevice device = allDevices[i];
                lsDevice.Items.Add(device);
            }
        }

        private PcapDotNet.Packets.Packet BuildEthernetPacket()
        {
            PcapDotNet.Packets.Ethernet.EthernetLayer ethernetLayer = new PcapDotNet.Packets.Ethernet.EthernetLayer();
            ethernetLayer.Source = new PcapDotNet.Packets.Ethernet.MacAddress("01:02:03:04:05:06");
            ethernetLayer.Destination = new PcapDotNet.Packets.Ethernet.MacAddress("01:02:03:04:05:67");
          ethernetLayer.EtherType = PcapDotNet.Packets.Ethernet.EthernetType.IpV4;

            ipV4Layer.CurrentDestination = new PcapDotNet.Packets.IpV4.IpV4Address("204.27.56.226");
                        ipV4Layer.Identification = (ushort)100;

            PcapDotNet.Packets.PayloadLayer payloadLayer = new PcapDotNet.Packets.PayloadLayer();
            payloadLayer.Data = new PcapDotNet.Packets.Datagram(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(txPrayload.Text));

            PcapDotNet.Packets.PacketBuilder builder = new PcapDotNet.Packets.PacketBuilder(ethernetLayer, ipv4layer, payloadLayer);
            return builder.Build(DateTime.Now);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need this? I seems to be like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I need to spoof my ip

Comment: It can't work with TCP connections. All you can do  is sending blindly some packets which will be possibly a nonsense packets for the receiver. So this is not the way of hiding you ip (while communicating with the server).